# How to use polylinedecorator plugins in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polyline-decorator

i'm new in html and leaflet, i don't know how to use plugins in leaflet
right now i'm working with polyline decorator plugins but i don't know how to use it right
i'm trying following tutorial on internet, here my code

```html
var arrow = L.polyline([[107.63576,-2.72322], [107.65699,-2.7366]], {}).addTo(map);
    var arrowHead = L.polylineDecorator(arrow, {
        patterns: [
            {offset: '100%', repeat: 0, symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 15, polygon: false, pathOptions: {stroke: true}})}
        ]
    }).addTo(map);
```

and here my head section

```html
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
     <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="polyline/dist/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js"></script>
  <script src="polyline/src/L.polylineDecorator.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: What happens? What should happen instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the latitudes and longitudes swapped in the call to `L.polyline`. Try this line instead:

```
var arrow = L.polyline([[-2.72322, 107.63576], [-2.7366, 107.65699]], {}).addTo(mymap);
```